# Unable to load video into UIVideoEditorController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

I am getting an error where the `UIVideoEditorController` is unable to find a video `URL` that has been loaded using a `UIImagePicker` and stored in an dictionary.

I am using the following but the canEditVideoAtPath is returning false for the following url:

```
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/83449852-2DC2-42AB-9FFA-C2C7931380C4/tmp/trim.28F7EE00-9F2E-4421-8E2B-8A70789CAFDE.MOV
```

Any idea why the following code would not work?

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[self.movieArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]] objectForKey:@"MovieURL"]);

NSString *videoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.movieArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]] objectForKey:@"MovieURL"]];

UIVideoEditorController *editorController = [[UIVideoEditorController alloc] init];

if([UIVideoEditorController canEditVideoAtPath:videoPath]){

    editorController.videoPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.movieArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]] objectForKey:@"MovieURL"]];
    editorController.delegate = self;
    editorController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;

    self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:editorController];
    self.popoverController.delegate = self;
    [self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

}
```

I get the error messages

```
The requested URL was not found on this server
```

Comment: is the object for key MovieURL a NSURL or NSString ?

Comment: I think it is an NSURL

Comment: The message coming back is No such file or directory", NSURL=file:///file:/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/18C9C9BB-6241-40C7-9230-A4852E31CAE9/tmp/trim.321E9C24-B2F7-43A9-B682-864770D62AC1.MOV}

Answer (score 2):

remove `file://` from the path string

Comment: I was having the exact same error using Swift and was stuck for days! Very strange that UIVideoEditorController.videoPath would add an extra "file://"

Answer (score 1):

Try using -(NSString *)path. The absolute URL won't work.

`[[[self.movieArray objectAtIndex:[sender tag]] objectForKey:@"MovieURL"] path]`